# Laravel Dusk 2.0 / Laravel 5.5 returns an empty page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I'm in the midst of upgrading my Laravel 5.3 website to 5.5 and unable to get Dusk working properly against my localhost. I have other unit tests working properly against my localhost but for some reason, Dusk returns `"<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>"` for any local page. Local pages seem to work fine browsing it on my desktop.

My DuskTestCase

```
protected function driver()
{
    $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--headless',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--ignore-certificate-errors'
    ]);

    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
        'http://localhost:9515',
        DesiredCapabilities::chrome()
        ->setCapability(WebDriverCapabilityType::ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
        ->setCapability('acceptInsecureCerts', true)
        ->setCapability(
            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
        )
    );
}
```

My Sample Test

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {

            $result = $browser->visit('http://localhost');
            $browser->screenshot('test');
            $browser->dump();
    });
}
```

- chrome driver works fine calling google.com and dumps content
- hardcoded the url to localhost for testing
- page is http not https
- tried php artisan serve before calling test, same result
- tried cache / config clear
- created an `.env.dusk.local` file, didn't seem to affect it
- chromedriver -v is `ChromeDriver 2.44.609551`
- tried 127.0.0.1 no dice

Comment: Try `APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000` in combination with `php artisan serve`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir just tried it out and still have the blank tags for some reason

Comment: Did you set `APP_URL` in your `.env` or `.env.dusk.local` file?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I have yes for both, I'm also hard coding the url in the visit method just for sanity and it does not work, curling the ip with port return a database connection error - I suspect it's because I'm running laradock it can't communicate to the database via the mysql connection but it connects fine using the apache2 container

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could make it working:

```
public function testBasicExample()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->visit(env('APP_URL').'/home')
                ->assertSee('Laravel');
    });
}
```